# Using binary values to address multiple pins Arduino/MCP23017

Tags: python, arduino, led

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to address multiple pins using binary values using the digitalWrite function? The documentation seems to indicate you can only use 1 pin per digitalWrite.
2. I am iterating through this array `int array4[] = {14, 10, 4, -1};`, and I don't want to turn on the LED represented by array4[3], for some reason -1 is actually activating a pin. Is there a 'null' value I can use in this regard?

I am porting some Python code to run on Arduino, and I ran into an issue when using multiple MCP23017 chips to turn on/off LED lights. I was able to turn on combinations of LEDs by using arrays of binary values in python.

With the Python program, I am able to address any combination of pins on a given MCP chip by using a binary string like: 0b10011011. For example, say this lights up LED 2, 4, and 6. Well, on the Arduino that same binary value lights up just one LED.

I understand I can activate multiple pins like:

```
int array1[] = {11, 6, 5, 0};
int array2[] = {12, 8, 2, 7};
int array3[] = {13, 9, 3, 1};
int array4[] = {14, 10, 4, -1};

mcp5.digitalWrite(array1[i],1);
mcp5.digitalWrite(array2[i],1);
mcp5.digitalWrite(array3[i],1);
mcp5.digitalWrite(array4[i],1);
```

But I would like to use my existing code for binary sequences and not re-write everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*The following assumes you are using the Adafruit MCP23017 library*

You can only write one pin at a time with `digitalWrite`. Here's the source:

```
void Adafruit_MCP23017::digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t d) {
    uint8_t gpio;
    uint8_t bit=bitForPin(pin);


    // read the current GPIO output latches
    uint8_t regAddr=regForPin(pin,MCP23017_OLATA,MCP23017_OLATB);
    gpio = readRegister(regAddr);

    // set the pin and direction
    bitWrite(gpio,bit,d);

    // write the new GPIO
    regAddr=regForPin(pin,MCP23017_GPIOA,MCP23017_GPIOB);
    writeRegister(regAddr,gpio);
}
```

You can see there is no error or bounds checking.

You could use this function as a basis to write your own `digitalWriteMany` function (or other suitable name). This function could also check for NULL values in your array.